# need to delete all lines from file that are contained in the line below

Tags: linux, command-line, vim

I have some files that look like this:

```
0
04
040
040t
040te
040tes
040test
040test2
041
041t
041te
041tes
041test
041test1
0n
0ne
0ne-
0ne-o
0ne-os
0ne-osx
```

I need to delete all the lines that are included in the line after them. IOW, I need to reduce it to this:

```
040test2
041test1
0ne-osx
```

Any suggestions for the Linux CLI or vim to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vim you could try this global command:

```
g/^\(.*\)\n\1.\+/d
│ ├────────────┘ │
│ │              └ delete the matching lines (see `:h :d`)
│ │
│ └ pattern matching 2 lines, the second one starting like the 1st
│
└ global command (see `:h :g`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lne 'print $prev if -1 == index $_, $prev;
           $prev = $_;
           END { print $prev }' -- file.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to `print`
- `$_` is the special variable that contains the actual line read from the input
- [index](http://p3rl.org/index) returns -1 if the substring (2nd argument) isn't found in the string (1st argument)
- the END block is needed to print the last line of the file

Comment: Thanks for the post. I assume that this works, but as I explicitly called out Vim, I'm going to mark the other response as the answer.